# Why message queues are not being used for any system level applications in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ipc

In my Linux machine, when i run 'ipcs' command, I have the below information listed

```
 srinivas@srinivas-G41MT-S2:~$ ipcs -a

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 0          srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 32769      srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 65538      srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 6684675    srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 131076     srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 163845     srinivas   600        12288      2          dest         
0x00000000 196614     srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 229383     srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 7208968    srinivas   600        262080     2          dest         
0x00000000 7241737    srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 393226     srinivas   600        393216     2          dest         

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    

srinivas@srinivas-G41MT-S2:~$
```

I do not understand why even a single application in my system is using Message Queues?

I have so many applications installed and have them running(Ubuntu OS). I used Message Queues in one of my C applications to transfer text messages between different threads.

Since I saw this, I have a feeling that Message Queues may not be ideal for data transfer as no one is using them. Is it completely safe to use message queues? Is there any possibility of memory corruption if we do not implement them properly?

Comment: Safety-wise I don't think there are any problems using SysV queues. It's just that most people use unix sockets these days.